# Получить ссылку на JSON файл из кода страницы

Tags: json

https://www.pgatour.com/players/player.34046.jordan-spieth.html
Одна из статистик / показателей, представленных в профиле игрока PGAT, - «Официальные деньги». Эта статистика получена из статического файла * .json. Нужно получить url этого файла. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка на JSON содержащий значение
https://statdata-api-prod.pgatour.com/api/clientfile/career?P_ID=34046&format=json

[image: Содержимое файла]

Для того, чтобы получить эту ссылку я перешёл на целевую страницу в хроме с открытыми инструментами разработчика (на клавиатуре `<F12>` или `<ctrl>+<shift>+<i>`). Перешёл на вкладку "Network" и указал в поиске, что меня интересуют JSON файлы. Потом дважды кликал на каждый из них и использовал `<ctrl>+<f>` для того, чтобы искать целеувую строку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как вы получили именно ссылку?

Comment: Обновил ответ))

Comment: интересно. я делал точно также но так и не получилось отыскать нужный json
видимо как то проглядел
спасибо большое)